# Rails FFMPEG - convert to webm gives error for encoder 'libvpx-vp9'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ffmpeg, libvpx, delayed-paperclip

I am testing video conversion to convert video file into mp4 and webm.
I have also setup ffmpeg and compiled properly.Mp4 conversion succeeds but webm breaks always complaining as  -

```
The encoder 'libvpx-vp9' is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.
```

its strange as I aready have vp8 present -

```
mike1011:~/workspace (s1) $ ffmpeg -encoders | grep -i vp
ffmpeg version git-2016-03-29-bf1495d Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-version3
  libavutil      55. 19.100 / 55. 19.100
  libavcodec     57. 32.100 / 57. 32.100
  libavformat    57. 29.101 / 57. 29.101
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 40.102 /  6. 40.102
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
 V..... libvpx               libvpx VP8 (codec vp8)
 V..X.. libvpx-vp9           libvpx VP9 (codec vp9)
 V..... wrapped_avframe      AVFrame to AVPacket passthrough
 A..... wavpack              WavPack
```

my model..video.rb looks like -

```
has_attached_file :video,
   :styles => {
      :mp4video => { :geometry => '1280x720>', :format => 'mp4',
        :convert_options => { :output => { :vcodec => 'libx264', :movflags => '+faststart',  :strict => :experimental} } },
      :webmvideo => { :geometry => '1280x720>', :format => 'webm',
        :convert_options => { :output => { :vcodec => 'libvpx-vp9'} } }, 
      :oggvideo => { :geometry => '1280x720>', :format => 'ogg',
        :convert_options => { :output => { :vcodec => 'libtheora',
          :acodec => 'libvorbis',  :strict => :experimental } } },
      screenshot: { geometry: '640x480#',  :convert_options => {
        :output => { :vframes => 1, :s => '300x169', :ss => '00:00:02'} } }
    },    
    :processors => [:transcoder],
     ###other setting comes here

  ##using delayed-paperclip for background processing of videos
  process_in_background :video

  def process_delayed!
    unless self.video.job_is_processing
      self.video.job_is_processing = true
      self.video.post_processing = true
      self.video.reprocess!
      self.video.job_is_processing = false
    end  
  end
```

I am sharing my complete output below(with error highlighted :)) -

```
    2.4.1 :003 > v=Video.find 25
      Video Load (1.8ms)  SELECT  "videos".* FROM "videos" WHERE "videos"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 25]]
     => #<Video id: 25, videoable_id: 9, videoable_type: "ThirdPartyCaterer", video_file_name: "Sample320.mp4", video_content_type: "video/mp4", video_file_size: 1105773, video_updated_at: "2019-02-02 00:17:37", duration: 18.112, slug: "sample320-mp4-dbb96526-5db1-4c59-9152-615fc077eca7", active: true, created_at: "2019-02-02 00:17:37", updated_at: "2019-02-02 00:17:37", video_processing: true> 
    2.4.1 :004 > v.process_delayed!
    [paperclip] copying /videos/25/original/Sample320.mp4 to local file /tmp/6b5665997c56c12544e7069276f6660b20190203-677953-1jsw8d1.mp4
    [paperclip] Trying to link /tmp/6b5665997c56c12544e7069276f6660b20190203-677953-1jsw8d1.mp4 to /tmp/6b5665997c56c12544e7069276f6660b20190203-677953-1qmn2uk.mp4
    I, [2019-02-03T00:12:09.849885 #677953]  INFO -- : Running transcoding...
    ["/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg", "-y", "-i", "/tmp/6b5665997c56c12544e7069276f6660b20190203-677953-1jsw8d1.mp4", "-s", "360x240", "-aspect", "1.5", "/tmp/2f51a6ecbce019dcad28a46b5be980ec20190203-677953-rh2lh0.mp4"]

    I, [2019-02-03T00:12:16.060391 #677953]  INFO -- : Transcoding of /tmp/6b5665997c56c12544e7069276f6660b20190203-677953-1jsw8d1.mp4 to /tmp/2f51a6ecbce019dcad28a46b5be980ec20190203-677953-rh2lh0.mp4 succeeded

    [paperclip] Trying to link /tmp/2f51a6ecbce019dcad28a46b5be980ec20190203-677953-rh2lh0.mp4 to /tmp/2961027361de4afbbb86f7764a034ee020190203-677953-1g0vvwe.mp4
    I, [2019-02-03T00:12:16.082499 #677953]  INFO -- : Running transcoding...
    ["/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg", "-y", "-i", "/tmp/6b5665997c56c12544e7069276f6660b20190203-677953-1jsw8d1.mp4", "-s", "360x240", "-aspect", "1.5", "/tmp/2f51a6ecbce019dcad28a46b5be980ec20190203-677953-fv3pzs.webm"]

    E, [2019-02-03T00:12:16.202420 #677953] ERROR -- : Failed encoding...
    ["/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg", "-y", "-i", "/tmp/6b5665997c56c12544e7069276f6660b20190203-677953-1jsw8d1.mp4", "-s", "360x240", "-aspect", "1.5", "/tmp/2f51a6ecbce019dcad28a46b5be980ec20190203-677953-fv3pzs.webm"]

    ffmpeg version git-2016-03-29-bf1495d Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
      built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1)
      configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-version3
      libavutil      55. 19.100 / 55. 19.100
      libavcodec     57. 32.100 / 57. 32.100
      libavformat    57. 29.101 / 57. 29.101
      libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
      libavfilter     6. 40.102 /  6. 40.102
      libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
      libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
      libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/tmp/6b5665997c56c12544e7069276f6660b20190203-677953-1jsw8d1.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : isom
        minor_version   : 512
        compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
        encoder         : Lavf57.76.100
      Duration: 00:00:18.11, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 488 kb/s
        Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 360x240 [SAR 32:27 DAR 16:9], 353 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : VideoHandler
        Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 129 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : SoundHandler

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX====== HERE COMES THE ERROR========XXXXXXXXXXXX
    [libvpx-vp9 @ 0x3e3dec0] The encoder 'libvpx-vp9' is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.

    Errors: encoded file is invalid. 

    Paperclip::Error: There was an error processing the transcoder for 6b5665997c56c12544e7069276f6660b20190203-677953-1jsw8d1
           ...
```

Comment: Upgrade ffmpeg. `2016-03-29` is too old.

Comment: Hi @Gyan, i have updated to ...>>>   ffmpeg version 2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 20160609....Is it the latest version? How can i get to know what is the latest version ?

Comment: Latest release is 4.1.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Gyan.Can you share me the link where i can see all the latest releases..?